# Nested fields indexing failing for elastic search

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

i have installed the following 
1.Elasticsearch 1.0.0  \
2.Mongodb 2.4.9 \
3.MongoDB River Plugin 2.0.0\
4.Mapper-attachments \

when  i  try to index the mongodb dataset with nested fields the following error it is raising

**[2014-05-13 16:49:58,442][ERROR][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiverBulkProcessor] Bulk processor failed. failure in bulk execution:
[0]: index [dava], type [dava_listings], id [5260ea6cfe821b3c2fd0d9ac], message [MapperParsingException[failed to parse [business.phone_numbers]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "(303) 427-9484"]; ]
[1]: index [dava], type [dava_listings], id [5260ea6cfe821b3c2fd0e524], message [MapperParsingException[failed to parse [business.phone_numbers]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [0]]; ]
[2]: index [dava], type [dava_listings], id [5260ea6cfe821b3c2fd0e5e7], message [MapperParsingException[failed to parse [business.phone_numbers]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [0]]; ]**

Comment: Post mapping and sample docs..!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first business.phone_numbers you indexed had a numeric-only value, so ES dynamically mapped it to a number.  You need to do a GET /index/_mapping to see what mapping it used.  You'll then have to delete your index, PUT the mapping (or create an index template if you are doing time series data), and then re-index your data.

Comment: tnq u very much for your reply ...as am being beginner to elasticsearch  am unable to follow the above steps could you please explain me in detail....

Comment: Add your current mapping to your question -- do a `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/dava/_mapping?pretty` to get it.

Comment: thnq u so much for your support can i have your mail id plz ..so that i will ask any queries ..plz
1103santhoshkumar.p@gmail.com  ping me to this mail please